# jQuery - Get Select Value and Update Div With Multiple Select Menus

Tags: jquery

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x9bbb14n/

As an example, I have the following HTML:

```
<select name="sweets">
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
  <option>Caramel</option>
  <option>Fudge</option>
  <option>Cookie</option>
</select>
<div class="sweets"></div>

<select name="cars">
  <option>Ford</option>
  <option selected="selected">Jaguar</option>
</select>
<div class="cars"></div>
```

I have this jQuery

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    var str = "";
    str = $( "select option:selected" ).text();
    $( "div" ).text( str );
  })
  .change();
```

I know it's incorrect but I want to be able to select one option and *its* DIV to be updated, then go to another menu, select an option and for it to update *its* DIV

Any obvious things I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **$(this)** for getting current object in jquery

```
$("select").change(function () {
  var str = $("option:selected", this).text();
  $('.' + $(this).attr('name')).text(str);
}).change();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x9bbb14n/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use current clicked element context along with next selector to target required div:

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
  var str = $(this).find("option:selected" ).text();
  $(this).next().text( str );
}).change();
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    var selectname = $(this).attr('name');
    var str = $(this).find("option:selected" ).text();
    $( "div."+selectname ).text( str );
  })
  .change();
```

I found this was best as the DIV could move around the page